# Return a result from an sql query

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to use the SQLSVR function to return a true or false from a query,
i was using ODBC_connect and ODBC_results.

This was my original script:

```
  function user_exists($username) 

{    
   $result = odbc_exec (odbc_connect("book", "", ""), "select count ('user_id') FROM [User] WHERE username = '$username'");
   return (odbc_result($result, 1) ? true : false); 
}
```

But trying to use the SQLSVR function im not sure where to go. This is what i have so far.

```
 function user_exists($conn, $username) {   

$sql =("select count ('user_id') FROM [User] WHERE username = '$username'");
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
$name = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 0);

     If ($name = 1) {
         Return True;
           }
     else{
          Return False;
           }
```

}

Comment: i am already connected to the server

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `$conn` to `user_exists()` otherwise it will not be visible in function body.

```
function user_exists($conn, $username) {
   ...
```

And also, you need to call `user_exists(...)` somewhere to make it all work. Putting function method is not equivalent of calling it.

**EDIT**

This code is redundant:

```
$test = sqlsrv_has_rows($result);
return (($test == true) ? true : false);
```

as it is sufficient to just:

```
return sqlsrv_has_rows($result);
```

Comment: i am calling on the function from another page, i have added to $conn to the function but it is still returning a false

Comment: tried executing your query manually to see if this is returning what you thing it should?